# Solving a system of 3 linear inequalities with 3 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, systems-of-equations

```
find lowest possible x, y and z whole number variables where:

x  =< 2y+2z 
6y =< x+z   
3z =< x+y
```

I am trying to solve this system of 3 linear equations with 3 unknowns and get the
ratio that x, y and z have to be in for the inequalities to work. 
So far I have been able to get a working ratio

**Q1** : but I am trying to get a ratio that satisfies the equations below.

```
x  = 2y+2z 
6y = x+z   
3z = x+y
```

**Q1, a** : And if no such ratio exists how can I mathematically determine that?

The formular I used to get a working ratio for the inequality is by solving the equation. I made the equations all equal to each other as follows:

```
0.5x + x  =  x + y + z 
  6y + y  =  x + y + z   
  3z + z  =  x + y + z
```

This way I was able to get the equation below.

```
1.5x = 7y = 4z
```

The equation above satisfies the first inequality but not the corresponding equation.

PS: I am not very conversant with the tags if I have left any out please add. Thank you.

Comment: Remark: the Stack Exchange system claims that I migrated this question from Mathoverflow (https://mathoverflow.net/posts/327772/revisions), but it is false.

Comment: The only solution of the system of *equations* is $(0,0,0)$. As the coefficients are small, you can try solutions by brute force. [$(5,1,2)$]

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is there no formular to get the suggested solution 5,1,2 I am trying to code an algorithm that solves such equations

Comment: @YulePale: no, use brute force.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: kindly help , how do I start brute forcing?

Comment: @YulePale: try increasing integers.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni This is not that relevant for the question, but why do you think that the information about the migration is not correct? (The link you gave seems to confirm it.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I never voted to migrate this question. I just voted to close it on MO (for a different reason).

Answer (score 1):

This can be formulated as a Mixed Integer Linear Programming problem (MILP).  To do so, you need to decide on an objective function to be minimized.

The statement "find lowest possible x, y and z whole number variables" is a little value. So we could separately solve 3 separate problems,, one for each objective function x, y, and z.

For instance, using YALMIP, this can be formulated as

```
intvar x y z;  % declares that x, y, and z are integer variables
optimize([x <= 2*y+2*z,6*y <= x+z,3*z <= x+y],x) % minimizes x subject to the constraints
value([x y z]) % displays optimal values of x, y, z
optimize([x <= 2*y+2*z,6*y <= x+z,3*z <= x+y],y) % same as above but objective function is y
value([x y z]) % displays optimal values of x, y, z
optimize([x <= 2*y+2*z,6*y <= x+z,3*z <= x+y],z) % same as above but objective function is z
value([x y z]) % displays optimal values of x, y, z
```

For each of the 3 problems, the optimal values of x, y and z are zero. So we have found the lowest possible x, y and z whole number variables under any reasonable interpretation.